# Apache 2.4 on CentOS 7 gives 500 error when ldap authentication added

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7

I have a new installation of CentOS 7 (3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64) fully patched.
It has apache 2.4.34-7 from centos-sclo-rh, and I have a properly signed certificate and certs for the companies cert-chain.

I can go to any page on the site if there is no LDAP authentication. The same pages  will display correctly with no authentication or with local file authentication.

However, if I add LDAP, I get "500 Internal Server Error". Nothing shows up in the ssl_error_log or other logs. I have log level at info and/or debug.

The kicker is that LDAP is succeeding. The user name appears in the ssl_access_log.

Any help on even debugging this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.

I didn't have the corporate certificates installed correctly. I had an old version of the bundle, and a new one came out earlier this year.